# Navigating the Prototype chain in javascript

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

```
function Student(name, age) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
}

Student.prototype.showDetails = function () {
  console.log(`${this.name}, ${this.age}`);
};

let Manish = new Student('Manish', 34);
console.log(Manish.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__);
console.log(Manish);
```

In the above code, the second last line

```
console.log(Manish.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__);
```

...logs `null` as expected. However when I manually navigate through the prototype chain using the object from the last line `console.log(Manish)`, I have to go down 5-6 levels of the `__proto__` property till I get a `null` value.

Is there some explanation for this difference?
[image: Image one]
[image: Image two]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the console output showing 5-6 levels, please?

Comment: The console implementation differs per browser. But I looked in Chrome and Firefox and didn't see an entry `__proto__` on the top level (which makes sense, as it is not an *own* property, but inherited). There is `[[prototype]]` (Chrome) or `<prototype>` (Firefox), but these are representations of the "internal slot" which is not a JavaScript property. Anyway, ... I couldn't see how you could be able to see 5-6 levels of `__proto__`.

Comment: @trincot pls check now..

Comment: Is that one screenshot in two images?!

Comment: did you find an answer to this yet?

Comment: @ezio Trincot's answer is spot-on

Answer (score 1):

The `__proto__` entry that you see in the third level in the console, is the *getter* function which you execute when you do `Manish.__proto__`. Realise that `Manish` does not have an own property with the name `__proto__`, it is by following the prototype chain that it makes access to the `__proto__` getter that you see in the console output.

Note also that the console output *executes* that getter to show you the object which is the *same* object it shows at the `[[Prototype]]` entry at the top level.

Key here is that when you access `__proto__` like you do, you execute a function (getter) that is defined higher up the prototype chain.

The `[[Prototype]]` entries are not JavaScript properties, but internal slots which are defined in the ECMA Script specification, but are not accessible as properties in JavaScript code. Console interfaces provide access to these slots to provide additional transparency, but it can also lead to confusion.